# Live Streaming phone to phone

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I am creating an application in which I want to display a live stream video from an Android phone using the application **IP Webcam** to a webpage. I have tried setting the `src` of the `<video>` tag in the website to the ip address of the stream (http://192.168.1.9:8080/video), but it doesn't work although I have tried it on VLC and it works.

Can you please help me with a way to display the streaming video on a webpage.

The help is much appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: No Error at all. This is the code I'm trying:
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
 <video src= "http://192.168.1.9:8080/video" width = "640" height="480">
  Invalid!
 </video>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IP Webcam serves its video stream as Motion JPEG, not MPEG or H.264 or WebM. Which just means you need to use an `<img>` tag instead of `<video>`. It still animates just like a video (at least in Firefox and Chrome).

```
<img src= "192.168.1.9:8080/video" width="640" height="480">
```

You can also repeatedly load http://*ipaddr*:*port*/shot.jpg to just grab still frames.